# Existe alguma forma de escrever um código pra web sem framework em python?

Tags: python, aplicação-web

Acho o python uma linguagem muito interessante. E como desenvolvo para web, gostaria de utilizá-lo para esse fim. Sei que existem frameworks bons como `Flask` e `Django`.

Mas, se eu quisesse escrever pequenos códigos apenas para testes, haveria alguma maneira de fazer isso em `python` sem utilizar frameworks para web?

Por exemplo, em PHP eu posso criar um script simples:

```
echo "Hello, World"
```

E em seguida rodar na linha de comando:

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

Isso criaria um servidor simples e rodar o meu "hello world".

Tem como fazer isso no `Python`?

Comment: A pergunta título para ter um pouco haver com a explicação da pergunta. Ou existem duas perguntas distintas aí. A resposta para o título é: sim, pode. A última pergunta é se o Python tem um servidor embutido? Isto é realmente o que deseja saber?

Comment: Mais ou menos @bigown. Quero saber se tem como fazer um `hello_world.py` e rodar ele pela linha de comando num servidor (do python mesmo) e aparecer lá num localhost da vida o resultado (no navegador). Tipo o do PHP, saca?

Comment: Como faz isso então, @bigown? No Python tem como "escrever algo pra imprimir no navegador"?

Comment: Eu não tenho grande conhecimento mas sei que diretamente não tem, precisa de ferramenta extra. Estou lendo sobre isto agora, talvez seja o que quer: http://waitress.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: A nível de ferramentas web, aquilo que melhor posso recomendar, daquilo que tenho experimentado, são linguagens, APIs, e frameworks, como `HTML5`; `PHP`; `CSS3`; `MYSQL`; `NOSQL` (ex.: `MONGODB`); `NODE.JS`; `ANGULAR.JS`; `RUBY ON RAILS`; e `SYCL`, por grau de dificuldade ascendente. Caso se interesse por computação gráfica, pode ainda optar por ferramentas como `WEBGL`. Destas ferramentas todas, aquilo que se aproxima mais do seu propósito a nível de paradigma de programação, e arquitectura de software é talvez o NODE, o `ANGULAR`, e o `RUBY ON RAILS`. Mais uma vez, é inútil tentar reinventar

Comment: Porque não utilizar flask ou django? By the way, dê uma olhada na biblioteca de CGI.

Comment: Como dito na própria pergunta: _Quero algo simples_

Comment: @PabloPalácios realmente, o "Quero algo simples" pode se enquadrar muito bem com a utilização do `Flask`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Primeiro, Python é uma linguagem totalmente diferente de PHP. Embora a documentação do PHP diga que essa linguagem seja de propósito geral, é inegável que ela esteja altamente relacionada com o desenvolvimento de scripts a serem rodados em um servidor web.

Diferentemente, Python é uma linguagem que, dentre várias outras coisas, também pode ser utilizada para desenvolvimento de web aplicativos. No entanto, em função dessa pluralidade de aplicações, o desenvolvimento aplicativos web feito puramente com Python é uma tarefa bastante complexa (em oposição ao seu *simples*).

Feita a introdução, minha resposta para a sua pergunta é **não**, não é possível. A resposta do tovmeod, até onde sei, só permite você iniciar um servidor web para gerir arquivos estáticos e não para rodar scripts em Python.

Seguindo a abordagem dele, e, como te sugeri nos comentários, você pode rodar scripts em Python como se fosse um script CGI. Logo, para fazer o seu *simples* "hello world" em Python você precisa:

1. Criar um diretório para servir os seus arquivos.
2. Dentro desse diretório, crie um subdiretório chamado cgi-bin
3. Lá, crie um módulo em python chamado hello.py com o seguinte conteúdo

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env python
   print("""Content-type: text/html

   Hello world from Python!""")
   ```
4. Mude as permissões do arquivo para ser executável
5. Inicie o servidor com a opção para servir scripts CGI:

   ```
   python -m http.server --cgi 8000
   ```
6. Visite localhost:8000/cgi-bin/hello.py e pronto.

Veja que, nessa abordagem, é necessário definir o cabeçalho Content-type pois, caso o contrário, o navegador poderá não entender e você fará o download do script em vez de executá-lo. O mesmo vale para o shebang na primeira linha.

Repare que, com essa mesma abordagem, você também consegue executar scripts em PHP, bastando apenas trocar o shebang.

Outra possibilidade é, em vez de criar um diretório raiz para rodar o servidor Python, utilizar a própria pasta cgi-bin do Apache (caso você esteja utilizando-o e ele esteja configurado para lidar com CGI). Isso pode deixar as coisas um pouco mais simples. Como disse no comentário, você pode utilizar a biblioteca cgi e cgitb, que podem descomplicar um pouco sua vida.

Mas enfim, meu ponto é, dificilmente você irá criar uma aplicação web com Python utilizando essas abordagens. Frameworks como Django e Flask estão aí para *simplificar* o desenvolvimento para web. No seu caso específico, fazer um hello world com Flask ficaria muito mais *simples*:

1. Instale o flask `pip install flask`
2. Crie o arquivo hello.py em qualquer lugar com o seguinte conteúdo:

   ```
   from flask import Flask

   app = Flask(__name__)

   @app.route('/')
   def hello():
       return 'hello from flask'

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       app.run()
   ```
3. Execute o script `python hello.py`
4. Visite `localhost:5000` e pronto.

Dessa forma você não precisou configurar uma estrutura de diretórios, não precisou lidar com shebangs, não precisou alterar permissões de arquivos e não precisou lidar com cabeçalhos HTTP.

Ok, são 10 linhas de Python, com decorator e tudo mais, mas, tente testar um POST usando apenas Python e CGI e depois teste um POST com Flask. Digo isso pois acredito que você não vai testar apenas "echo hello worlds"...

Answer (score -1):

Sim, você pode usar o módulo `SimpleHTTPServer`.

Você pode rodar simplismente:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

ou colocar isso no seu código:

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

PORT = 8000

Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print("serving at port", PORT)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

veja: https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html

Se estiver usando Python 3, o módulo agora se chama `http.server`, os exemplo são parecidos:

rode:

```
python -m http.server 8000
```

ou adicione dentro do seu código:

```
import http.server
import socketserver

PORT = 8000

Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print("serving at port", PORT)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

veja mais em:

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/http.server.html

Comment: Tá, e como você vai rodar scripts em python com isso?

Comment: sobreescreve do_GET

Comment: Realmente, se você tentar executar um script `python` dessa forma, ele fará o download do arquivo ou então exibirá o conteúdo do script. Na verdade, essa é uma forma do python criar um servidor para executar apenas `HTML` e afins.