# Python Web sem Framework

Tags: python, aplicação-web, framework

Se tem duas linguagens que eu gosto muito são python, que sempre usei pra desktop e php, que sempre usei pra web.

Gostaria de usar o python pra web também, mas atualmente estudo pelo framework django, que embora tenha N funcionalidades úteis, não me agrada nem um pouco pelo simples fato de eu detestar frameworks.

Gostaria de saber se tem um jeito de programar em python pra web sem usar um frameworks, assim como sempre fiz em php.

Comment: http://klauslaube.com.br/2012/11/02/entendendo-o-cgi-fastcgi-e-wsgi.html

Comment: Não consegui entender qual é a dificuldade nisso. Pelo que eu saiba, a linguagem funciona normalmente, basta instalá-la no servidor e vai funcionar da mesma maneira que o PHP funciona. Só precisa ajustar o PATH corretamente.

Comment: Ja estive nesse dilema e cheguei na seguinte conclusão: Que dá para fazer o que vc quer dá, mas para ficar minimamente aceitável, vc vai ter que desenvolver seu próprio framework, mesmo que vc não tenha consciencia disso ou chame por outro nome. Lembrando que PHP tb tem vários (ia dizer dezenas, mas n tenho cereza) frameworks (Lavarel, Symfony, Cake, CodeIgniter,  Yii, e por ai vai)

Comment: O que chega mais perto de ser um framework que eu uso pra php é o bootstrap, mas não é exatamente um framework.

Comment: Não precisa reinventar a roda.

Comment: Acho que é duplicada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86587/existe-alguma-forma-de-escrever-um-c%C3%B3digo-pra-web-sem-framework-em-python