# Python substitui apenas o PHP ou substitui o PHP e o apache?

Tags: php, python, apache

A primeira linguagem que eu aprendi foi PHP, infelizmente. O PHP roda junto com o apache, mas eu queria usar python ao invés, mas os tutoriais que encontrei a respeito de python pra web fazem parecer que ele substitua o apache, é isso mesmo? Eu tenho que configurar ele pra fazer o papel do servidor?

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/243240/5878

Comment: www.cursoemvideo.com melhor lugar do mundo pra iniciar em Python

Comment: Com certeza, Guanabara é o melhor mas será que vai chegar na parte de web?

Answer (score 1):

No [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/) (o framework web python mais difundido) roda-se um servidor por baixo dos panos para facilitar a escrita da sua aplicação. Esse servidor roda no ambiente de desenvolvimento, ou seja: Na sua maquina. Quando seu site for posto *'no ar'*, é comum usar um servidor diferente como o Apache.

A diferença do PHP para o Python é que no PHP você usa de fato um server apache, em desenvolvimento. Com Python isso é facilitado durante o desenvolvimento e aplicado somente em produção.

[Documentação Django sobre uso do Apache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/)

[Aplicação pratica passo-a-passo sobre o tema](https://blog.luisfred.com.br/como-usar-o-django-com-o-apache/)